# spark Dataframe vs pandas-on-spark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm quite new to pySpark but I'm confused about the difference between a spark Dataframe (created for example from an RDD ) and a pandas-on-spark Dataframe.

- Are those the same object ? Looking at the type it seems they are different classes.
- What's the core difference, if any ? (I know that working with pandas-on-spark Dataframe you can use almost the same syntax of Pandas on a distributed Dataframe but I'm wondering if is only this one the difference )

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the end of this notebook will help you understand the difference。https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/pandas-to-pandas-api-on-spark-in-10-minutes.html

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pandas-vs-pyspark-dataframe-with-examples/

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/dataengineering/comments/te0m0x/pandas_on_spark_vs_pyspark_dataframe/

Answer (score 6):

Answering directly:

**Are those the same object ? Looking at the type it seems they are different classes.**

> No, they are completely different objects (classes).

**What's the core difference, if any ?**

> A pySpark DataFrame is an object from the PySpark library, with its own API and it can be constructed from a wide array of sources such as: structured data files, tables in Hive, external databases, or existing RDDs.

> A Pandas-on-Spark DataFrame and pandas DataFrame are similar. However, the former is distributed and the latter is in a single machine. When converting to each other, the data is transferred between multiple machines and the single client machine.

> A Pandas DataFrame, is an object from the pandas library, also with its own API and it can also be constructed from a wide range of methods.

Also, I recommend checking this documentation about [Pandas on Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/pandas_pyspark.html)

Comment: Yes, everything you said is correct but I think my question was more about if there is a real difference between working with a pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame and with a pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame. 
They are different classes, belonging to different module, and they will have different methods etc..That's fine. But is there any logical or physical difference on how spark perform and manage transformation ? 
For example, the two similar trasnromfations,  pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy() and pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame.groupby() how they differ ?

Comment: ok, so when you ask "is there any logical or physical difference" between working with a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` and with a `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame`", my answer is yes for physical, because the data is being distributed across the nodes in your cluster. Regarding the logical bit, the only main difference I can tell is the order of the indexes (spark ignores row indexing in operations), so on the groupby() example, you may see the grouping index having a different order than pandas, but the aggregation logic should still return the same result.

Comment: Sorry, but also in the second case (`pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame`) the data is being distributed across the nodes. That was my question. I see the difference between `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` and `pandas.DataFrame` and the fact that in the second case the data are not distributed. But working with `pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame` your data should be distributed as well as in the case of `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`. So, from the physical point of view I still can't see the difference. About the logical difference, I see, thanks for bring me to my attention this point.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I swapped terms for a second there, you are right both `pyspark.sql` and `pyspark.pandas` classes are distributed, but they are likely to be distributing `pandas.DataFrame` under the hood with the `pyspark.pandas` wrapper. So from the physical point, there will still be write/read operations in memory and partitions operations should still be identical on both. The only thing I can point out is that you can make lazy operations in `pyspark.sql`, which then will only compute when `.collect()`

Comment: Can you construct `pyspark.pandas.DataFrame` from `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`?

Comment: yes, you can do `sdf.to_pandas_on_spark()`

Comment: Can I say both `pyspark.pandas` and `pyspark.sql` are equally efficient?

Comment: efficiency will depend on your end goal. As said above, `pyspark.sql` uses lazy operations but `pyspark.pandas` may be a more convenient API